# How to create a menu check button in checked mode in perl Tk?

Tags: perl

I would like to create a menubar checkbutton in a "checked" state.

It seems that creating the menubar checkbutton according to the documentation will create it in an "unchecked" state.

How can i create it in a "checked" state (or onvalue state)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `widget` demo, click on *Menus / 1. Menus and cascades (sub-menus).* When you click on *Cascades* there, click on *Check Buttons* - two of the check buttons are checked. The relevant code is located in `menus.pl`:

```
my $cc = $c->cascade(-label => '~Check buttons', -tearoff => 0);

$cc->checkbutton(-label => 'Oil checked', -variable => \$OIL);
$cc->checkbutton(-label => 'Transmission checked', -variable => \$TRANS);
$cc->checkbutton(-label => 'Brakes checked', -variable => \$BRAKES);
$cc->checkbutton(-label => 'Lights checked', -variable => \$LIGHTS);
# ...
my $cc_menu = $cc->cget(-menu);
$cc_menu->invoke(1);
$cc_menu->invoke(3);
```

Setting the variables to the respective onvalues also works.